# How do I add a Canban board to the matermost(self-hosted)?

Tags: mattermost

I have no idea how to add Kanban Board in Mattermost(self-hosted version).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to :

1. Activate the mattermost board/focalboard plugin
2. Create a Channel , all channels have their own boards.
3. Create a board view for that board.

Read the more here for more details
https://docs.mattermost.com/guides/boards.html